# Как объединить массивы с одинаковым элементом?

Tags: python

Есть список массивов типа `[ ['1234', '5678', '1'], ['1234', '9012', '2'] ]`.
Я хочу находить все массивы с одинаковым первым элементом и добавлять значения в один общий. То есть должно получится вот это: `['1234', '5678', '1', '9012', '2'].` К решению даже близко не подобрался.

Comment: У всех списков первый элемент должен совпадать с первым элементом первого списка? То есть если будут списки [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 5], [2, 1, 6]], то итоговый вывод - [1,2,3,1,2,4]?

Comment: @Павел Почти. Единица должна присутствовать всего один раз первым элементом. [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]

Comment: Понял, сейчас скорректирую решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
list_collection = [['1234', '5678', '1'], ['1234', '9012', '2'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

desired_element = list_collection[0][0]

filtered_lists = [list_[1:] for list_ in list_collection if list_[0] == desired_element]

joined_list_collection = [desired_element] + [element for list_ in filtered_lists for element in list_]

print(joined_list_collection) # ['1234', '5678', '1', '9012', '2']
```

Comment: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list что может эта ошибка значить? ругается на joined_array_list

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров какой-то из списков вы создали через круглые скобки вместо квадратных? Тогда у вас получился не list, а tuple, это уже другая структура данных

Comment: просто я получаю данные с бд и никак не могу их редактировать

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров тогда надо было конкретно указать эти данные в условии, у вас указан явно - list. Круглые скобки в питоне - это уже не list

Comment: да, прошу прощения

Comment: что нужно изменить, чтобы тоже самое получилось с кортежами?

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров на будущее: один тикет - один вопрос. Если возникают новые, то лучше создать ещё один.
Если исходные данные - кортежи, то нужно заменить результат слияния перед принтом на (desired_element,) + sum(filtered_lists, ())

Comment: Стократно благодарен вам!

Comment: `sum(filtered_lists, [])` - хороший способ согреть процессор и пользователя пока он ожидает результат конкатенации.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тем не менее, это одно из самых популярных решений на англоязычной версии сайта https://stackoverflow.com/a/716489/19736488

Comment: Сделайте `a = [[0]] * 100000` и сравните время работы `b = [x for lst in a for x in lst]` с `b = sum(a, [])`. Первое работает мгновенно, второе работает десятки секунд.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy соглашусь, разница ощутима, решение отредактирую.

Answer (score 1):

Если объединять списки, с одинаковым первым элементом `'1234'` только из первого списка:

```
a = [['1234', '5678', '1'], ['1234', '9012', '2']]

def qwe(lst_0, *lst_n):
    yield from lst_0
    for l0, *ls in lst_n:
        if l0 == lst_0[0]:
            yield from ls

q = list(qwe(*a))
print(q)  # ['1234', '5678', '1', '9012', '2']
```

Если объединять списки, с одинаковыми первыми элементами `'1234' и '1235'` из любых списков:

```
a = [['1234', '5678', '1'], ['1235', '658', '4'], ['1235', '5575', '5'], ['1234', '9012', '2']]

def qwe(lst_n):
    dt = {}
    for l0, *ls in lst_n:
        dt.setdefault(l0, [l0]).extend(ls)
    return list(dt.values())


q = qwe(a)
print(q)  # [['1234', '5678', '1', '9012', '2'], ['1235', '658', '4', '5575', '5']]
```